# Elsa Workflow resume from previous activity

Tags: elsa-workflows

I'm trying to return an elsa 3 code based workflow to previous activity from outside the workflow i.e. not from an activity in the Workflow.

I believe I can use WorkflowExecutionContext.ScheduleActivity but I can't seem to find a way of getting a reference to the context even though I have the WorkflowInstanceId.

I've also tried ResumeWorkflowAsync with the ResumeWorkflowRuntimeOptions.ActivityId populated but the workflow does not continue to run from that point.